# Powering cmos invertor from battery charging line

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, cmos

I use MCP73831/2 for charging a battery. But now I have to power a logic gate from the same line (I mean connect gate's vcc directly to the battery and to charger output). Is it a good idea? Could the logic IC be damaged somehow by charger current? The rest of my circuit is disconnected from the battery with a mosfet while charging.

Comment: It's not a great idea but it might work in some cases.  You'll need to provide a schematic of the setup with actual details such as voltage, charge current, inverter type, etc.   Likely there are much better ways to solve your real problem, so be sure to include an explanation of your ultimate goal when you edit your question to supply all of what is missing.

Comment: The MCP73831T-2ACI/OT will keep the voltage below 4.2V, and the lowest voltage you will see depends on how far you let the battery discharge. The rest depends on the logic gate you intend to use and what you are trying to achieve, see previous comment.